# how to create csv using 2 csv info?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, join

I have two  csv tables with schema of

table `A as (Name,X,Y,date,time,millisecond,type1)`

and

table `B as (Name ,X,Y,date,time,millisecond,type2)`

I want table `C with schema (X,Y,type1,type2)` where `X,Y,time` of table must be same millisecond may not be same.How can I do this?

Table A:

```
    Edp,1116,313,23/6/2020,7:25:48,637,ToBolled
    Edp,1155,313,23/6/2020,7:25:50,899,ToItaled
    Edp,1155,313,23/6/2020,7:25:51,14,ToItaled
    Edp,1198,308,23/6/2020,7:25:53,217,ToUndled
    Edp,1198,308,23/6/2020,7:25:53,323,ToUndled
    Edp,1198,308,23/6/2020,7:25:53,431,ToUndled
```

Table B:

```
    Edp,1155,313,23/6/2020,7:25:50,891,dou
    Edp,1198,308,23/6/2020,7:25:53,211,tri
```

Result table:

```
 Edp,1155,313,23/6/2020,7:25:50,899,ToItaled,dou
 Edp,1198,308,23/6/2020,7:25:53,431,ToUndled,tri
```

Comment: ' must be same millisecond may not be same' - come again?

Comment: may not be same

Comment: Not with you , can you add sample data and expected outcome as text please.

Comment: now can you pls see question again

Comment: What is *a csv table*?

Comment: comma seperated values

Comment: There is no logic I can see for arriving at the result.

Comment: @gmb https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html

Comment: so we cant make  result table from 2 tables?

Comment: @P.Salmon: thank you! I learnt something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for a join:

```
select a.*, b.type2
from tablea a
inner join tableb b 
    on  b.name = a.name
    and b.x    = a.x
    and b.y    = a.y
    and b.date = a.date
    and b.time = a.time
```

This brings records from both tables that have the same `(name, x, y, date, time)`. You might want to adjust the conditions for your exact use case.

Comment: How to do this for csv?

Comment: In MySQL CSV is just a storage engine (as explained in the link given by P.Salmon in a comment to your question), so you can query the tables like you would with other storage engines.